# Changing padding with localstorage does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a two buttons for changing the padding on my website. They work, however I have to set to padding for nav, main and footer manually in the CSS. Here is the code:

```
main {
    padding: 20px 25%;
}
footer {
    padding: 5px 25%;
}
nav {
    padding: 0 25%;
}
```

```
    var padding = 15;

    $('#paddingPlus').click(function() {
        switch(padding) {
            case 0:
                changePadding(5);
                padding = 5;
                break;
            case 5:
                changePadding(10);
                padding = 10;
                break;
            case 10:
                changePadding(15);
                padding = 15;
                break;
            case 15:
                changePadding(20);
                padding = 20;
                break;
            case 20:
                changePadding(25);
                padding = 25;
                break;
            case 25:
                changePadding(30);
                padding = 30;
                break;
            case 30:
                alert('You have reached the maximum amount of padding!');
                break;
        }
    });

    $('#paddingMinus').click(function() {
        switch(padding) {
            case 0:
                alert('You have reached the minimum amount of padding!');
                break;
            case 5:
                changePadding(0);
                padding = 0;
                break;
            case 10:
                changePadding(5);
                padding = 5;
                break;
            case 15:
                changePadding(10);
                padding = 10;
                break;
            case 20:
                changePadding(15);
                padding = 15;
                break;
            case 25:
                changePadding(20);
                padding = 20;
                break;
            case 30:
                changePadding(25);
                padding = 25;
                break;
        }
    });

    function changePadding(pad) {
        $('nav').css('padding', '0 ' + pad + '%');
        $('main').css('padding', '20px ' + pad + '%');
        $('footer').css('padding', '5px ' + pad + '%');
    }
```

I tried to do this with localstorage so that it saves the padding, but it doesn't work and chrome shows me no error-message. Here is the code:

```
main { }
footer { }
nav { }
```

```
    switch(localStorage.getItem('padding')) {
        case 0:
            changePadding(0);
            localStorage.setItem('padding', 0);
            break;
        case 5:
            changePadding(5);
            localStorage.setItem('padding', 5);
            break;
        case 10:
            changePadding(10);
            localStorage.setItem('padding', 10);
            break;
        case 15:
            changePadding(15);
            localStorage.setItem('padding', 15);
            break;
        case 20:
            changePadding(20);
            localStorage.setItem('padding', 20);
            break;
        case 25:
            changePadding(25);
            localStorage.setItem('padding', 35);
            break;
        case 30:
            changePadding(30);
            localStorage.setItem('padding', 30);
            break;
        default:
            changePadding(15);
            localStorage.setItem('padding', 15);
    }

    $('#paddingPlus').click(function() {
        switch(localStorage.getItem('padding')) {
            case 0:
                changePadding(5);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 5);
                break;
            case 5:
                changePadding(10);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 10);
                break;
            case 10:
                changePadding(15);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 15);
                break;
            case 15:
                changePadding(20);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 20);
                break;
            case 20:
                changePadding(25);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 25);
                break;
            case 25:
                changePadding(30);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 30);
                break;
            case 30:
                alert('You have reached the maximum amount of padding!');
                break;
        }
    });

    $('#paddingMinus').click(function() {
        switch(localStorage.getItem('padding')) {
            case 0:
                alert('You have reached the minimum amount of padding!');
                break;
            case 5:
                changePadding(0);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 0);
                break;
            case 10:
                changePadding(5);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 5);
                break;
            case 15:
                changePadding(10);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 10);
                break;
            case 20:
                changePadding(15);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 15);
                break;
            case 25:
                changePadding(20);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 20);
                break;
            case 30:
                changePadding(25);
                localStorage.setItem('padding', 25);
                break;
        }
    });

    function changePadding(pad) {
        $('nav').css('padding', '0 ' + pad + '%');
        $('main').css('padding', '20px ' + pad + '%');
        $('footer').css('padding', '5px ' + pad + '%');
    }
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me where my error is.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the previous answer, does this help?

```
$('#paddingPlus').click(function() {
   let padding = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('padding'));
   if (padding >== 30) {
      alert('You have reached the maximum amount of padding!');
   } else {
      padding += 5;
      changePadding(padding);
   }
}


$('#paddingMinus').click(function() {
   let padding = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('padding'));
   if (padding === 0) {
      alert('You have reached the minimum amount of padding!');
   } else {
      padding -= 5;
      changePadding(padding);
   }
}

function changePadding(pad) {
        localStorage.setItem('padding', pad);
        $('nav').css('padding', '0 ' + pad + '%');
        $('main').css('padding', '20px ' + pad + '%');
        $('footer').css('padding', '5px ' + pad + '%');
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there still needs to be a function to set the padding when the page is loaded. Could you show me that pls?

Comment: Nevermind, I already wrote it myself. Thanks for you answer, this is so much simpler than my code :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert a padding which you get from `localStorage.getItem('padding')` to `Number` (i.e. `parseInt(localStorage.getItem('padding'))`). When you get an item from `localstorage`, it returns an `String` so your `case` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is partly due to the type coercion from a string to an integer when dealing with the `pad` value and also due to the fact that your second code example does not update the localStorage value.

You can solve both of these issues and simplify the code by simply adding to the value in each event handler instead of using the `switch` statement, and also by reading the value from `localStorage` instead of relying on the global variable. Try this:

```html
<nav>Navigation</nav>
<main>Main content</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>

<button class="padding" data-change="5">+</button>
<button class="padding" data-change="-5">-</button>
```

```js
function setPadding(pad, change) {
  pad = pad == null ? 15 : parseInt(pad, 10);
  pad += (parseInt(change, 10) || 0);

  if (pad < 0) {
    alert('You have reached the minimum amount of padding!');
    return;
  }

  if (pad > 30) {
    alert('You have reached the minimum amount of padding!');
    return;
  }

  localStorage.setItem('padding', pad);
  $('nav').css('padding', '0 ' + pad + '%');
  $('main').css('padding', '20px ' + pad + '%');
  $('footer').css('padding', '5px ' + pad + '%');
}

// retrieve the value and set when the page loads
setPadding(localStorage.getItem('padding'));

// update the value when either button is clicked
$('.padding').click(function() {{
  setPadding(localStorage.getItem('padding'), this.dataset.change);
});
```

Here's a working example of this in a [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hwLfkq7o/), as SO snippets are restricted from accessing localStorage.